# "No Return Found" error in simple mysql function

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-function

I'm using xampp with phpMyAdmin to manage a MySql database.
When creating a function I got a "No Return Found" error, so I stripped down the function to narrow the origin of the error I got to the simplest case where it still doesn't work.

[image: Code]

And the error message is this:

[image: Error message]

Apparently if the `RETURN` statement isn't the only thing on the code I get an error.

Comment: What about starting *definition* by `BEGIN` and ending it with `END` ?

Comment: @Cid Yeah, I realized that. For some reason I thought phpMyAdmin would do that automatically

Comment: PHPMyAdmin's routine generator is a bit problematic as it requires you to structure your desired code inputting differently to if you are writing the SQL yourself from scratch.

Comment: Try this: `Defeinition: "BEGIN
    SET @c = 0;
    RETURN @c;
END"`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the actual code being executed against MySQL is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `Contagem`() RETURNS INT(11)
SET @c = 0;
RETURN @c;
```

This will fail, because you have not wrapped the function in `BEGIN`...`END`.

Try instead to write this as your function declaration:

```
BEGIN
    SET @c = 0;
    RETURN @c;
END;
```

Alternatively, declare the function yourself directly in MySQL:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION `Contagem`() RETURNS INT(11)
BEGIN
    SET @c = 0;
    RETURN @c;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: That's exactly right. The error message shows the code being executed without begin and end.

Answer (score 1):

When reviewing this post I was reading more carefully the error message I realized the MySql code to define the function didn't have `BEGIN` and `END` in it.

I assumed when typing function code with several lines that phpMyAdmin would know how to handle it, since the code text box has support to multiple lines of code.

So, putting `BEGIN` at the beginning and `END` at the end of the code solved my problem.

Comment: My best advice would be to type yourself the `CREATE FUNCTION` statements